# Rails create and new creating different objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model Project and a model Test. Project has many Tests.

My `tests_controller` has:

```
def new
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @test = @project.tests.new
end

def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @test = @project.tests.create(test_params)
end
```

So in my `new.html.erb`, I present a form which calls `new`, and when submit is pressed, `create` is called. I'm confused however because what is apparently happening is that I am creating one test in `new` and a whole different test in `create`. What is the correct paradigm for what I am trying to achieve?

The reason I am creating a new test in `new` is because I want my create form to know the id of the to-be-created test object.

Comment: They are different objects because they are not persisted between requests. But in the first action you are not actually creating the test, you are just instantiating the Test class. What is your question exactly?

Comment: @depa how then would I persist them between requests? What is the typical way this is handled?

Comment: Why would you want to persist them? You don't have the data to persist it in the first action, that only happens in the second one because you have test_params. This is the typical way this is handled.

Comment: @depa I want, when I am presenting the create form, for the form to know the would-be id of the new test object. This is why in the `new` method I am creating a test object.

Comment: You won't know the primary key until you actually save it to the database. You don't have any validations that prevent you from persisting an empty object?

Comment: @depa well what I'd like to do is save it to the database in the `new` method so I can get an id, then just update it with the new form values in the `create` method.

Comment: OK, fair enough. But then you should be using #create and #update and skip #new altogether, to be consistent with REST. Are you sure you don't need validations though? You would be departing a bit from convention. Not that it's a problem in itself, but it's good to have a (good) reason for it.

Answer (score 0):

the `create` action should look something like this:

```
  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @test = @project.test.create(params[:test])
    if @test.save
      redirect_to SOME_path, flash: { success: "Test added successfully" }
    else
      flash.now[:error] = "Something's gone wrong.  Please try again!"
      render 'new' 
    end    
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Why doesn't Rails persist objects in the `#new` controller action?

1. **HTTP Request consistency**

   All `#new` actions are mapped to GET requests, which shouldn't be used to create resources. Creating resources can be done in two ways: the non-idempotent way, by using `#create` which maps to POST; and the idempotent way, by using `#update` which maps either to PUT (or PATCH in some cases). The latter is the way to go when you want to create resources whose id you already know.
2. **Validations**

   The whole idea behind validations is they should be applied *before* persisting data. So in the `#new` action we usually limit ourselves to instantiating the model class, and then in the `#create` action we can have at least two possible responses -- a successful one when validations have been cleared and the object has been persisted, and an unsuccessful one when we got errors upon persisting the object.
3. **Keeping your database clear of empty objects**

   Another reason why `#new` and `#create` are distinct actions is that the server could lose the connection to the client between them. And, when that happens, you don't want an empty object sitting in your database because the second action never came through.

That said, if you still have a strong reason to persist objects before asking for user input **and** you have no need for validations and you don't mind having empty objects in your database, you could do it by skipping the `#new` action altogether, kinda like this:

```
def create
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @test = @project.tests.create
end

def update
  @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
  @test = @project.tests.update(test_params)
end
```

Comment: The problem I'm having is that I am using `form_for([@project, test]..`, and if I don't call new, then I won't be given the chance to set up, and both @project and test will be nil, and thus no form.

Comment: But you are *supposed* to base your form on an empty object for new objects. Can you tell me the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: Tell that to Rails..I get an exception: `First argument in form cannot contain nil or be empty`, and it's referring to the form_for line.

Comment: OK, this is why you should always tell the whole story when asking a question. Please try using simply `@test = Test.new` in your `#new` action.

Comment: Yes but now when I hit submit on the form, the test I created in new is going to be disregarded in the create method. I need to keep track of its id.

Comment: The reason I want to keep track of its id is this: I press a button called "Add test", which is a remote call that executes some Javascript that renders the test's form and adds it to a table. The HTML id of this form is automatically set to "new_test". When I hit submit on the form, I want to be able to delete this "new_test" element from the page with Javascript. However, I could have multiple new_test forms on the page, and therefore would not be able to grab the right form and delete it. So what I wanted was the HTML id to be "new_test_<#test_id>", so that I could reference it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37017/discussion-between-depa-and-maq)